# Wiring connections for lights in commercial building producing strange results

Tags: neutral, ground

I am having a rough time. Exit sign  black and white connect to exit sign . It doesn't come on. But when the ground wire is connected to to the neutral wire the lights come on. Other end pole that has security lights not coming  on or connected the right way. I am lost on what to do about this. This is a commercial  building

Comment: Unless you are a licensed electrician, doing any electrical work on a commercial building is a violation. You are only allowed, in most jurisdictions, to do electrical work on your own home.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is Hone Improvement not Commercial Problems.

Answer (score 1):

You have a broken neutral wire. The most likely place is at a junction box somewhere in the circuit - either a miswire or a connection that came apart. There is a small possibility that the problem is actual *wire* damage, but that is much less likely.

As to why the "ground to neutral" fix works, that is because ground and neutral are connected in the main panel. When you connect ground to neutral elsewhere, the current that should flow on neutral flows on ground instead, and since that is connected in the main panel, the lights work. This is great for testing - you have diagnosed the basic problem. But you can't use that as a fix because it is against code and not safe.